# Wearing a PhD gown with a stole bestowed earlier from my Masters

Tags: graduation, academic-dress

I am an academic staff member with a PhD degree. I am curious whether I can put on my valedictorian stole bestowed upon me from my masters degree (from another university) with my PhD gown, i.e. I would like to wear my PhD gown with my masters stole at future commencement ceremonies. Is this commonly done? Is it a social faux pas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is commonly done and few would notice. It might seem a bit weird to the (very) few who did notice, but they won't reduce your salary or fire you for such a thing.

Wearing two stoles might also be a bit weird, but why the heck not?

Caveat: Maybe in Austria or Switzerland there might be some issues. They are very formal places. But, still, more likely to generate a laugh than a frown.

If you do happen to get pushback you can decide whether to repeat the performance, of course. And, be ready to explain your reasoning.

Comment: My gut is that it's technically a faux pas since the combined costume is probably not valid academic dress of any institution, but also that in practice nobody gives a flip unless you look wildly ostentatious or are under greater scrutiny (giving a speech, serving a highly visible role in a ceremony, etc.)